# Will my new graphics card be supported with my current hardware configuration?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I want to add a graphics card in my PC. My choice is an AMD Radeon R7 265X or nVidia GTX 750 Ti or AMD Radeon R9 270X. But I'm confused, my motherboard doesn't support 4GB RAM modules! I have 2*2GB RAM modules in my motherboard's slots.

Will my graphics card be supported with my configuration? If not, then to what extent can I use any latest graphics card?

My Configuration:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-G41MT-S2P
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 2.93GHz (E7500)
- RAM : 2 x 2GB 1333
- PSU: Corsair CX500

Comment: what does your mobo's supported RAM have to do with your choice of graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the choice of your graphics card has nothing to do with the RAM.

Also your motherboard supports 4GB RAM modules because as stated in the [specifications](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3743#sp) it supports up to 8GB RAM in 2 slots (so it supports 2 x 4GB).

On the same specificationss page you see that your motherboard features a PCI Express x16 slot which is compatible with the 3 graphics cards you mentioned.